# call webservice using NSMutableURLRequest in monotouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, parameter-passing

I try to save a capture image from iPhone to server. I done with Xcode. code like

```
NSMutableURLRequest  *request= [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";

NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];

[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: attachment; name=\"%@\" filename=\"Test.png\"\r\n", imgName] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setHTTPBody:body];

NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:delegate];
```

Now I try with monotouch,

here I create connection, send request & receive response is working fine.

But here I don't know how to set Header & Body to NSMutableURLRequest, simply I need to know how to pass parameters (like above Xcode).

```
NSMutableUrlRequest request = new NSMutableUrlRequest(new NSUrl("http://url.com"), NSUrlRequestCachePolicy.ReloadRevalidatingCacheData, 20);
request.HttpMethod = "POST";

var connectionDelegate = new TestNSURLConnectionDelegate();
var connection = new NSUrlConnection(request, connectionDelegate);
connection.Start();
```

Can any one help me for this...

Comment: if you are using Xarmain, the best approach is to use the standard C# methods for doing a web service call (WebClient or HttpWebRequest) like you would in any other .NET program.

Answer (score 0):

Using System.Net to get access to HttpWebRequest.

You just have to post to the url.. and write the byte[] of the image to the body of the request.

In my Example.. the ServiceBase value maps to a static string, and the "Service.SubmitImage" is a static string pointing to a service method endpoint.

```
 public void SubmitImage(byte[] image)
    {
        var request = WebRequest.Create(ServiceBase + Service.SubmitImage);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        request.ContentLength = image.Length;
        Stream str = request.GetRequestStream();
        str.Write(image, 0, image.Length);
        str.Close();
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    }
```